# How do I store the contents of a JSON file so that I can retrieve multiple JSON objects and their data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to get the data contained in multiple JSON objects from a .JSON file and output them to the user through a method. Each object contains two pieces of data - an message for an assignee and a general message for everyone else.

Here is the contents of the JSON file:

```
{
"Submitted":[
    {
        "assigneeMsg":"This is a new translation job. As a TL-Approver, you are required to provide an estimated delivery date and a price for the job upon transitioning the issue.", 
        "generalMsg":"This job has been submitted to TranslationLoft for review. Upon review, TranslationLoft will reply with a quote containing the price and estimated delivery date."
    }
],
"tl-quoted":[
    {
        "assigneeMsg":"TranslationLoft have approved the job for translation and have quoted an estimated delivery date and the cost to complete the job. As a Client-Approver, you have the option of accepting or rejecting this quote. If you choose to reject the quote, please leave a comment detailing your reasons. Once rejected, TranslationLoft can choose to requote the job if possible but may decide to close the job before progressing further. Upon acceptance of the quote, TranslationLoft will be able to progress with the job as stated.", 
        "generalMsg":"The quote has been sent to the client for review. Please wait for the client to respond with their acceptance or rejection of the quote."
    }
],
"client-accepted":[
    {
        "assigneeMsg":"The quote has been accepted by the client and translation can begin.", 
        "generalMsg":"Acceptance of the quote has been delivered to TranslationLoft. Please wait while the job is transitioned and translation begins."
        }
],
"Client-Rejected":[
    {
        "assigneeMsg":"The quote has been rejected by the client. Please provide a new quote or close the job with a reason for the closure.", 
        "generalMsg":"Rejection of the quote has been delivered to TranslationLoft. Please wait while TranslationLoft reviews the quote and makes their decision regarding a requote."
    }
]
}
```

And here is a snippet from the function where I want to output the message:

```
if (issueStatus === "Submitted") {
  if (user === issueAssignee) {
    msg = ;
  } else {
    msg = ;
  }
} else if (issueStatus === "tl-quoted") {
  if (user === issueAssignee) {
    msg = ;
  } else {
    msg = ;
  }
} else if (issueStatus === "Client-Rejected") {
  if (user === issueAssignee) {
    msg = ;
  } else {
    msg = ;
  }
} else if (issueStatus === "client-accepted") {
  if (user === issueAssignee) {
    msg = ;
  } else {
    msg = ;
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to retrieve the data from the JSON file so that in my function, I could then call, for example:

```
msg = Submitted[0].assigneeMsg;
```

So that msg will then have the data from assigneeMsg.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp

Comment: Is this code that you want to run in a browser? Are you serving both the page as well as the JSON file from a web server?

Comment: have you tried JSON.parse(jsonText)?

Comment: Parse the json to an object, and use that:
var obj = JSON.parse(yourJson);

Then in your code 
if (issueStatus === "Submitted") {
  if (user === issueAssignee) {
    msg = obj.Submitted[0].assigneeMsg;
  } 

and so on.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_files.asp

Comment: @BrandnDeRosier Yes, this is being run from a browser. The page as well as the JSON file are on the same server.

Comment: @furia1521 I'm not very familiar with JSON so could you explain to me how I would use this to retrieve the data from each object?

Comment: @MasterDex Try var message = JSON.parse(jsonText); and message would be an object and you can use it easier.

Comment: @Kush Thank you, this helps. Could you tell me how I load the json from the file? Can I use the path to the file in place of yourJson .i.e. "myJson.json"?

Sorry if this is all rather basic stuff, I'm just diving into json now.

Comment: json is not in proper format....can u update it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you're asking specifically about how to STRUCTURE the data, not how to retrieve it. If you know how to retrieve the JSON data in a general sense, than I believe this is what you want:

```
{
    "Submitted": [
        {
            "assigneeMsg": "Assignee Message 0",
            "generalMsg": "General Message 0"
        },
        {
            "assigneeMsg": "Assignee Message 1",
            "generalMsg": "General Message 1"
        },
        {
            "assigneeMsg": "Assignee Message 2",
            "generalMsg": "General Message 2"
        }
    ],
    "tl-quoted": [
        {
            "assigneeMsg": "Assignee Message 0",
            "generalMsg": "General Message 0"
        },
        {
            "assigneeMsg": "Assignee Message 1",
            "generalMsg": "General Message 1"
        },
        {
            "assigneeMsg": "Assignee Message 2",
            "generalMsg": "General Message 2"
        }
    ],
    "client-accepted": [
        {
            "assigneeMsg": "Assignee Message 0",
            "generalMsg": "General Message 0"
        },
        {
            "assigneeMsg": "Assignee Message 1",
            "generalMsg": "General Message 1"
        },
        {
            "assigneeMsg": "Assignee Message 2",
            "generalMsg": "General Message 2"
        }
    ],
    "Client-Rejected": [
        {
            "assigneeMsg": "Assignee Message 0",
            "generalMsg": "General Message 0"
        },
        {
            "assigneeMsg": "Assignee Message 1",
            "generalMsg": "General Message 1"
        },
        {
            "assigneeMsg": "Assignee Message 2",
            "generalMsg": "General Message 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

This structure allows you to retrieve each `Submitted` object like this:

```
assignee = Submitted[0].assigneeMsg; // Assignee Message 0
general = Submitted[0].generalMsg; // General Message 0
```

And another:

```
assignee = Submitted[1].assigneeMsg; // Assignee Message 1
general = Submitted[1].generalMsg; // General Message 1
```

**EDIT:** HOW TO RETRIEVE JSON

This code should be enough for you to get the data. This is assuming that the JSON file is on your server at a location like: http://example.com/json/myJsonFile.json

```
// XML HTTP Request and empty object
var request = new XMLHttpRequest ();
var myObject = {};

// Function to run when request finishes
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        myObject = JSON.parse (request.responseText);
    }
};

// Send request for the JSON
request.open ('GET', '/json/myJsonFile.json', true);
request.send ();
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps somewhat. I would also like to know how I retreive the information specifically from the json file too.

For example, I have the json content in "json/myJsonFile.json". How do I pull all the objects from that json file into my script?

Comment: @MasterDex See my edit for how to retrieve the data :-)

Comment: Using this, would I put 
`assignee = myObject.Submitted[0].assigneeMsg; ?`

Comment: @MasterDex Yes. There are situations where you may not need the `myObject`, such as in `for ()` or `Object.forEach ()` loops. But for directly accessing the object items, yes, that is proper.

Answer (score 2):

Im not really clear with your problem, but from what I understand this might fix a lot of your issues:

```js
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  switch (issuesStatus) {
    case "Submitted":
    case "issueAssignee":
    case "Client-Rejected":
    case "client-accepted":
      status(issuesStatus, user, data[issuesStatus])
      break;
  }
});

function status(issueStatus, user, message) {
  msg = issueStatus[message[user]];
}
```

You need to adjust everything for your own purposes, but it might help you on the way